# Why can't I reach my servlet from this form?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, forms, scriptlet

You don't have to go through the complete code. Just look at the first table assigning and document.write() inside body tag. I created the complete page using document.write() inside one script. At the end of the code you can see there is submit button before form is closed. When I run the page and click the submit  button it doesn't go to the servlet...What is wrong here ?

```
<%@page import="s_pack.dbManager"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org     
/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">

        table = '<form action = "AM2Servlet" method = "get" >'
        document.write(table);
        table = '<select name = "selected_course_id_in_marking">'
        document.write(table);

        var c_id,s_name;
        <%
            String co_id = request.getParameter("course_id_QSParam");
            System.out.println(co_id);
        %>
        c_id = '<%=co_id%>'

        document.write('<option>'+c_id+'</option>');
        table = '</select>'
        document.write(table);

        table = '<select name = "selected_student_in_marking">'
        document.write(table);
        <%
            String due_student_list[] = dbManager.get_students_with_due_result(co_id);
            for(int i=0;i<due_student_list.length;i++)
            {
        %>
                s_name = '<%= due_student_list[i]%>'
                document.write('<option>'+ s_name + '</option>');
        <%
            }
        %>

        table = '</select>'
        document.write(table);
        table = '<table  border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">'
        document.write(table);
        <%
            for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
            {
        %>
                temp = '<%=i%>'
                table = '<tr><td> In Course '+temp
                table = table + ' Mark: <select name = "InCourse'+temp+'Mark">'
                document.write(table);
                for(var mark=0; mark<=30;mark=mark+.5)
                {
                    document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
                }
                document.write('</select></tr>');
        <%
            }
        %>

        <%
            for(int i=1;i<2;i++)
            {
        %>
                temp = '<%=i%>'
                table = '<tr><td> Assignment '
                table = table + 'Mark: <select name = "Assignment'+temp+'Mark">'
                document.write(table);
                for(var mark=0; mark<=10;mark=mark+.5)
                {
                    document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
                }
                document.write('</select></tr>');
        <%
            }
        %>

        <%
            for(int i=1;i<2;i++)
            {
        %>
                temp = '<%=i%>'
                table = '<tr><td> Project '
                table = table + 'Mark: <select name = "Project'+temp+'Mark">'
                document.write(table);
                for(var mark=0; mark<=40;mark=mark+.5)
                {
                    document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
                }
                document.write('</select></tr>');
        <%
            }
        %>

        <%
            for(int i=1;i<2;i++)
            {
        %>
                temp = '<%=i%>'
                table = '<tr><td> Lab '
                table = table + 'Mark: <select name = "Lab'+temp+'Mark">'
                document.write(table);
                for(var mark=0; mark<=60;mark=mark+.5)
                {
                    document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
                }
                document.write('</select></tr>');
        <%
            }
        %>

        <%
            for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
            {
        %>
                temp = '<%=i%>'
                table = '<tr><td> Viva '+temp
                table = table + ' Mark: <select name = "Viva'+temp+'Mark">'
                document.write(table);
                for(var mark=0; mark<=10;mark=mark+.5)
                {
                    document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
                }
                document.write('</select></tr>');
        <%
            }
        %>

        <%
    for(int i=1;i<2;i++)
    {
%>
    temp = '<%=i%>'
    table = '<tr><td> Attendance '
    table = table + 'Mark: <select name = "Attendance'+temp+'Mark">'
    document.write(table);
    for(var mark=0; mark<=10;mark=mark+.5)
    {
        document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
    }
    document.write('</select></tr>');
<%
    }
%>

<%
    for(int i=1;i<2;i++)
    {
%>
    temp = '<%=i%>'
    table = '<tr><td> Semester Final '
    table = table + 'Mark: <select name = "SemesterFinal'+temp+'Mark">'
    document.write(table);
    for(var mark=0; mark<=60;mark=mark+.5)
    {
        document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
    }
    document.write('</select></tr>');
<%
    }
%>
        table = '</table></form>'
        document.write(table);

 table = '<hr> </br></br>'
 table = table + '<h1> Additional Exams </h1> <hr>'
 document.write(table);
 table = 'Name of Exam: <input type = "text" name="AdditionalExam1">  Obtained Mark:'
 document.write(table);
 table = '<select name = "AdditionalExam1Mark">'
 document.write(table);
 for(var mark=0; mark<=100;mark=mark+.5)
 {
    document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
 }
 document.write('</select>');

 table = 'Name of Exam: <input type = "text" name="AdditionalExam2">  Obtained Mark:'
 document.write(table);
 table = '<select name = "AdditionalExam2Mark">'
 document.write(table);
 for(var mark=0; mark<=100;mark=mark+.5)
 {
    document.write("<option>"+mark+"</option>");
 }
 document.write('</select>');
 table = '<input type="submit" value="Assign Marks"></form>'
 document.write(table);

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure you are handling the get method in servlet.. AND remove the unnecessary code, instead post some snippet of generated html and handler method from servlet, Will you please?

Comment: And you shouldn't do all this in the jsp, it's bad bad practices...

Comment: I am new to jsp. This is first time I am working with this.

Comment: Try to avoid Scriplet, instead use JSTL or Expression Language to avoid such errors. Scriplet mix HTML and JAVA together and makes it complex to find out the issue. Keep business logic and user interface logic in separate layers.

Comment: first of all, document.write will not be used here, because it will replace the whole page with the given string in write method

Comment: if u are doing first time then learn jsp little more deap, so u may be more cmfrtable to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a mistake in closing the form. Closed it twice..

Comment: that's why i asked for the rendered output.. did it solve your problem??